# How to autofill one field on change another field

Tags: community, custom-object

Below is my **Featured Program** object
I wanna autofill **Featured Programs Name** when I `select` or `change` **CMS**

[image]

> As you can see when I changed **CMS** now no new name here and I had
> to manually enter the name of program

[image]

**Is it even possible to achieve what I want?**

Comment: This is definitely possible but you're going to need to use one of the following: a workflow rule, a flow, or an Apex trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved it with Formula Field. It was pretty easy actually.

Steps to setup a Formula field:

1. First Go to **Setup**
2. Click on **Object Manager**
3. Choose your **custom object** from list (`Featured Program` in my case)
4. Click on **new field**
5. Setup a `field as Formula`, on the formula screen click on **Advanced Formula** -> **Insert Field** here you can choose the another field in your layout and choose its sub-field to insert in your **Formula Field**